# How to optimize a recursive bin packing algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, bin-packing

Here comes the wall of text.

For the company I work for we spec lengths of tube of varying lengths. For a given project lets say there is a list like this

100', 115', 105', 205', 195', 240', 240', 130', 180', 140', 225', 85'

The goal is to figure out how to cut the different lengths of tube from as few rolls as possible to reduce waste. We use rolls of 1000', 500', and 300'. We also figure 15' of extra tube per grouping. So a 1000' roll only takes 985' from the 1960' total for the project, 485' of a 500' and 285 of 300. So this project would need 2 1000' rolls.

I already have logic for determining how many of each roll type will be needed.

I start the recursive function like so

```
public static bool RecursiveLoopGroup(Int32 remainingLength, List<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry> loops, int[] bundlesNeeded, ref List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Int32>> dt1000, ref List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Int32>> dt500, ref List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Int32>> dt300)
    {
        Debug.Print("\nStarting RecursiveLoopGroup Method");
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Int32> returnDict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Int32>();
        List<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry> modifiedLoopList = new List<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>(loops);
        List<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry> skipEntries = new List<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>();
        System.Collections.DictionaryEntry lastEntry = new System.Collections.DictionaryEntry();
```

The returnDict is a dictionary of the loops that get grouped for return. So if

Group 1 : 100', 115', 105', 205', 195', 240'

Was found to be a good group, these would be returned in returnDict, wit their keys being unique numbers specific to each length of tube. More on that later.

The modifiedLoopList is a copy of the loop List given. This is so as the function gets called recursively I can pass the reduced list to the new iteration.

skipEntries is to keep track if which loops have been tried to be grouped with the current working group, but were not effective. More on that later.

and lastEntry is to keep track of the last loop that was added to the current working group. It is used to remove the last loop from the group is a solution can't be found with the current configuration.

The algorithm is this

Determine which size group the current iteration is working on 1000', 500', or 300'

Look at each loop starting from the front of the list, if adding it to the group will not go over the limit of the group, add it.

Once you've formed a group, call the recursive function with the list of remaining loops, and repeat until each loop is in a group.

So far this looks like this

```
bool success = false;//exit condition for while loop
        while (!success)
        {
            //since you cant edit the loop list while iterating, must save loops added to loop group to be removed after
            List<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry> loopsToRemove = new List<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>();

            //loop through each loop in the modfiedLoopList, which is the list of all the loops to use
            foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in modifiedLoopList)
            {
                //check if adding the loop will put the group over the limit or not
                if (groupTotal + (Int32)entry.Value <= groupLimit && skipEntries.Count > 0)
                {
                    bool entryIsInSkipList = false;//exit condition for the foreach loop
                    //check if the current entry is on the list of entries to skip
                    foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry skip in skipEntries)
                    {
                        if (entry.Equals(skip))
                        {
                            entryIsInSkipList = true;
                            break;//breaks the foreach loop, since the entry was on the skip list
                        }

                    }
                    //if the entry was on the skip list, then move to the next entry
                    if (!entryIsInSkipList)
                    {
                        groupTotal += (Int32)entry.Value;
                        loopsToRemove.Add(entry);
                        totalRemaining -= (Int32)entry.Value;
                        returnDict.Add((String)entry.Key, (Int32)entry.Value);//the dictionary that will be returned by each iteration, which contains the loops as entries that get treated as a group
                    }
                }//end if adding entry will go over limit
                else if(groupTotal + (Int32)entry.Value <= groupLimit)//need this else incase there are no entries in the skip list yet
                {
                    groupTotal += (Int32)entry.Value;
                    loopsToRemove.Add(entry);
                    totalRemaining -= (Int32)entry.Value;
                    returnDict.Add((String)entry.Key, (Int32)entry.Value);
                }
            }//end foreach entry in loopList

            //remove used loops from list after iterating
            foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in loopsToRemove)
            {
                modifiedLoopList.Remove(entry);
            }

            //if the list count is not zero, there are still loops to place
            if (modifiedLoopList.Count != 0)
            {
                Debug.Print("\nThere are " + modifiedLoopList.Count.ToString() + "Loops left");
                Debug.Print("\nReturn Dict = " + returnDict.ToArray().ToString());

                #region reset number of needed bundles and exit
                //If each bundle is 0, then your in the last group being formed.
                //if your in the last group being formed and there are still some left
                //then the current grouping fails, so add the loop group this iteration is on and return up
                //to the iteration before
                if (bundlesNeeded[0] == 0 && bundlesNeeded[1] == 0 && bundlesNeeded[2] == 0)
                {
                    if (groupLimit == 1000)
                        bundlesNeeded[0]++;
                    else if (groupLimit == 500)
                        bundlesNeeded[1]++;
                    else if (groupLimit == 300)
                        bundlesNeeded[2]++;
                    return false;
                }
                #endregion number of needed bundles and exit

                bool needToUndoLast;

                if (groupTotal < (groupLimit - slackAmount)) needToUndoLast = false;
                else needToUndoLast = RecursiveLoopGroup(totalRemaining, modifiedLoopList, bundlesNeeded, ref dt1000, ref dt500, ref dt300); //if the iteration called by this fails, then something might be wrong with this groups configuration.

                //So remove the last entry, adding it to the skip list so the same grouping isn't tried again, and try another grouping
                //configuration with the next loop in the list
                if (!needToUndoLast)
                {
                    
                    //if the return dictionary is empty, then all the loops are on the skip list
                    //so a configuration could not be found SEE ELSE
                    if (returnDict.Count != 0)
                    {
                        System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<String, Int32> lastDictEntry = returnDict.ElementAt(returnDict.Count - 1);
                        lastEntry = new System.Collections.DictionaryEntry((String)lastDictEntry.Key, (Int32)lastDictEntry.Value);
                        Debug.Print("\nNeed to undo last. Last Entry is" + lastEntry.Key.ToString() + "," + lastEntry.Value.ToString());
                        groupTotal -= (Int32)lastEntry.Value;
                        totalRemaining += (Int32)lastEntry.Value;
                        returnDict.Remove((String)lastEntry.Key);
                        skipEntries.Add(lastEntry);
                        //int returnIndex = loops.IndexOf(lastEntry);
                        modifiedLoopList.Add(lastEntry);

                        purgeSkipList(skipEntries);
                    }
                    else//so add back the needed loop length, and return to the iteration before so it can try a differnt configuation
                    {
                        if (groupLimit == 1000)
                            bundlesNeeded[0]++;
                        else if (groupLimit == 500)
                            bundlesNeeded[1]++;
                        else if (groupLimit == 300)
                            bundlesNeeded[2]++;
                        return false;
                    }


                }//end need to undo if
                else
                {
                    success = true;//if an undo isn't needed, then the iteration that was called succeeded, which means all groupings work
                }

            }//end if list has remainnig loops
            else
            {
                success = true;//no remaining loops, all have been sorted properly
            }


        }//end while loop
```

the PurgeSkipList function is to keep the skip list in order based on the unique number for each loop, which increment more or less.

I think running through an example with the list from above will help. I'll use pictures to help. It's important to know we don't want to make perfect rolls of 1000', 500', and 300' but give 15' of slack on each. So the total taken from the remaining unassigned loops can be 985', 485', and 285'

So first we start with the unsorted list

[image]

The algorithm would start from the top and select all it can that will fit into a total of 985'

[image]

Then the function would be called recursively and the next group would start being created

[image]

At this point the last 85' loop can't be added as it would create create a 1000' group and we can only go to 985'. So this recursive call would return false, meaning it failed to compeletly sort all the loops.

This would then trigger the group above it to remove the last loop in the group, add it to a skip list so the same configuration is not tried again. Then go back through all the remaining loops again and find the next one to try and create a finished group. I'll now just show the step as it's just a cycle now

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see the last instance would work for both loops. The grouping works best when the loop being built is as close to 985' as possible. I've implemented a check right after checking if there are any more loops, to see if the loop being built is close enough, and if it's way off then the rest of the iterations would be a waste since it would all result in a fail. So I'm trying to stop unnecessary recursion when possible.

This method worked pretty quickly for this list, but when I move to a [normally large group](https://warmboard-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/nshupe/EdloP2T4cLxArpC_0cvoAkcBkmnszGMdN-CbnvUoqpjr-A?e=X7TVsi), or our [extreme edge case](https://warmboard-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/nshupe/EWMwNo90vKJPoaBHSf-D-7UBUIPNbD5Kt-qJZfWkai-KQA?e=T6lbcH), it never seems to find a solution. So any help trying to optimize, I realize is a big ask, but would help a lot, Thank you.

Comment: That is indeed a wall of text. How wide is a saw blade?

Comment: Would also point out this question might be better suited to codereview.se

Comment: I hadn't heard of codereview.se but I'll check that out, thank you @CaiusJard